# add values to the array object key by clicking the button with this value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have three buttons that when clicked I want to add a value to a selected field that is added dynamically:

```
const [Fields, setFields] = useState([
 { value: [], current: true }, 
 { value: [], current: false }
]);
```

`value` - is the key I want to add values to when the button is clicked

`current` - these key store the state of the selected field when the field is clicked on

```
const [Fields, setFields] = useState([
 { value: [], current: true }, 
 { value: [], current: false }
]);

<button onClick={() => {}} data-value="A">A</button>
<button onClick={() => {}} data-value="B">B</button>
<button onClick={() => {}} data-value="C">C</button>

{Fields.map((field, i) => {
    return (
      <div key={i}>
        <div
          onClick={() => {
            setFields((oldArr) => {
              let newArr = oldArr.map((item, index) => {
                return {
                  ...item,
                  current: index === i ? true : false,
                };
              });
              return newArr;
            });
          }}
        >
          field.value <=== here need to add here the value from the buttons `data-value` on click
        </div>
      </div>
)})}
```

I just want to add symbols from buttons (`data-value`) on click to the key `value` if the neighboring key `current` is true. For example, if **A** and **B** are alternately clicked, we should add **AB** to key `value`.

If we alternately click in a different order **B** and **A**, we get **BA**.

Comment: So I understand right, when the button is clicked you want the `data-value` of that button to be appended the `value` array for the object that has `current: true`? What if they click the same button multiple times? Are you open to changing the data structure of `Fields`? Since this would be both easier, more robust, more readable and more performant if we do (I will explain in the answer).

Comment: @adsy, yes, if you click on a key with attribute `data-value`, that symbol will be added to the `value` array if the neighboring key `current: true`. If you click the same button multiple times, the symbol will be added multiple times. For example, if you click once on a key with **A**, and click three times on the **B**, you will get **ABBB**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, it's probably better to change the data structure of `Fields` a little. The current structure increases complexity but for no real gain. Specifically, there is a `current` key per object, but it seems that you are only really allowed to have one entry that is current at any given time.

However, the data structure theoretically could end up in a bad state, where multiple entries are current. Generally, it's best to avoid that and use a more concise data structure that has only the absolute minimum amount of information to achieve the goal. This will reduce complexity, be more readable and reduce the surface area for bugs. It is of course perfectly possible with the old structure, but we may as well clean up as we go along.

In this case, the bare minimum canonical bits of data you need are the values, and also a *index pointer* to the "current" entry. We can use two state items for this (note, that the overall accuracy of what is stored is more concise). This removes some "impossible" states from being "possible".

```
const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);
const [Fields, setFields] = useState([
 { value: [] }, 
 { value: [] }
]);

const handleButtonClick = (e) => {
  setFields((prev) =>
    Object.assign([], prev, {
      [currentIndex]: {
        value: [...prev[currentIndex].value, e.target.dataset.value],
      },
    }),
  );
};

<button onClick={handleButtonClick} data-value="A">A</button>
<button onClick={handleButtonClick} data-value="B">B</button>
<button onClick={handleButtonClick} data-value="C">C</button>

{Fields.map((field, i) => {
    return (
      <div key={i}>
        <div
          onClick={() => setCurrentIndex(i)}
        >
          {field.value.join('')}
        </div>
      </div>
)})}
```

Also, note it's more usual in React to just use the JS scope to pass around things like the "button value" as opposed to `data-` attributes. Unless you have a good reason for exposing that (using it to target them for testing maybe). That would look like this:

```
const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);
const [Fields, setFields] = useState([
 { value: [] }, 
 { value: [] }
]);

const appendToCurrent = (buttonValue) => {
  setFields((prev) =>
    Object.assign([], prev, {
      [currentIndex]: {
        value: [...prev[currentIndex].value, buttonValue],
      },
    }),
  );
};

<button onClick={() => appendToCurrent('A')}>A</button>
<button onClick={() => appendToCurrent('B')}>B</button>
<button onClick={() => appendToCurrent('C')}>C</button>

{Fields.map((field, i) => {
    return (
      <div key={i}>
        <div
          onClick={() => setCurrentIndex(i)}
        >
          {field.value.join('')}
        </div>
      </div>
)})}
```

Comment: I like the second way with `appendToCurrent('A')` better, and agree about `currentIndex`. Thanks a lot!